# Find root to leaf path with given sum. Code succeeds with string, fails with list

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I am looking at a binary tree problem. The goal is to find all path(s) from root to leaf, such that the values on the path sum up to a given *k*.

For that purpose I have written the same algorithm in two different ways:

1. The first version uses a string parameter `a`.
2. The second version uses a list parameter `a`.

They are supposed to give the same path result, but the second version prints a path that includes almost all the values in the tree.

#### Version 1

```
def rootToLeafPathsSumToK(root, k, a):
    if root == None :
        return None
    
    if root.left==None and root.right==None:
        if root.data==k:
            print(a+ str(root.data)+" ")
        return

    a+=str(root.data)+" "
    rootToLeafPathsSumToK(root.left,k-root.data,a)
    rootToLeafPathsSumToK(root.right,k-root.data,a)
```

**output:**

```
5 6 2 
5 7 1
```

#### Version 2

```
def rootToLeafPathsSumToK(root, k, a):
    if root == None :
        return None
    
    if root.left==None and root.right==None:
        if root.data==k:
            a.append(root.data)
            print(a)
        return

    a.append(root.data)
    rootToLeafPathsSumToK(root.left,k-root.data,a)
    rootToLeafPathsSumToK(root.right,k-root.data,a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between these two code snippets is:

- In the first version, where `a` is a string, you execute `a+=str(root.data)+" "`. This creates **a new string** and assigns it to the local variable `a`. This operation does not affect the string that the caller had passed as argument. Moreover, strings are immutable in Python.
- In the second version, where `a` is a list, you execute `a.append(root.data)`. This **does not** create a new list. It mutates the list that the caller had passed as argument. In fact, that code only has **one list**. So all `append` calls affect *that* single list.

So, where in the first version, the effect of adding a value is local and does not impact the caller's string, in the second version the effect is reaching also to the caller, since they use the *same* list.

To apply the same *local* principle in the second code version, replace the call to `append` with this:

```
a = a + [root.data]
```

Now the original list `a` is not mutated. Instead a new list is created, and assigned back to the local variable `a`. But here, the caller's list is still the original list. There is now a new list created.